# Django is not redirecting to profile page after login. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

This is my views.py

```
def LoginPage(request):
username = password = ''

next = ""

if request.GET:  
    next = request.GET['next']
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(request, username = username, password = password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        if next == "":
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/Profile/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
context = {}
return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```

This is my template:

```
{% if next %}
        <form class="" action='/Profile/' method="post">
            {%else%}
            <form class="" action="/Login/" method="post">
                {% endif %} {% csrf_token %}
                <p class="login-field-title"><strong>Username*</strong></p>
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-10 log-inp-field" placeholder="Enter Username" required>

                <p class="login-field-title"><strong>Password*</strong></p>
                <input type="password" class="form-control col-lg-10 log-inp-field" placeholder="Enter Password" required> {% for message in messages %}
                <p id="messages">{{message}}</p>
                {% endfor %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg col-lg-10 log-btn">Log In</button>
            </form>
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Some help would be very appreciated. Even after logging in with a registered user it is not redirecting me to the desired page and when i change the action, even with the un registered user it redirects me to the next page.

Comment: Your input tags are missing `name` attribute  .These attribute gets submited to server so currrently there is no `name` attribute so nothing gets submit. To fix this add `name="username"` and `name="password"` to your inputs .

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your settings file
`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'YOUR_PROFILE_URL`'